# Recommended way to do multiple shell commands with shell()

Tags: shell, snakemake

In snakemake, what is the recommended way to use the shell() function to execute multiple commands?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can call `shell()` multiple times within the `run` block of a rule (rules can specify `run:` rather than `shell:`):

```py
rule processing_step:
    input:
        # [...]
    output:
        # [...]
    run:
        shell("somecommand {input} > tempfile")
        shell("othercommand tempfile {output}")
```

Otherwise, since the run block accepts Python code, you could build a list of commands as strings and iterate over them:

```py
rule processing_step:
    input:
        # [...]
    output:
        # [...]
    run:
        commands = [
            "somecommand {input} > tempfile",
            "othercommand tempfile {output}"
        ]
        for c in commands:
            shell(c)
```

If you don't need Python code during the execution of the rule, you can use triple-quoted strings within a `shell` block, and write the commands as you would within a shell script. This is arguably the most readable for pure-shell rules:

```py
rule processing_step:
    input:
        # [...]
    output:
        # [...]
    shell:
        """
        somecommand {input} > tempfile
        othercommand tempfile {output}
        """
```

If the shell commands depend on the success/failure of the preceding command, they can be joined with the usual shell script operators like `||` and `&&`:

```py
rule processing_step:
    input:
        # [...]
    output:
        # [...]
    shell:
        "command_one && echo 'command_one worked' || echo 'command_one failed'"
```

Answer (score 4):

Thought I would throw in this example. It maybe isn't a direct answer to the user's question but I came across this question when searching a similar thing and trying to figure out how to run multiple shell commands and run some of them in a particular directory (for various reasons).

To keep things clean you could use a shell script.

Say I have a shell script `scripts/run_somecommand.sh` that does the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
input=$(realpath $1)
output=$(realpath $2)
log=$(realpath $3)
sample="$4"

mkdir -p data/analysis/${sample}
cd data/analysis/${sample}
somecommand --input ${input} --output ${output} 2> ${log}
```

Then in your Snakemake rule you can do this

```
rule somerule:
    input:
        "data/{sample}.fastq"
    output:
        "data/analysis/{sample}/{sample}_somecommand.json"
    log:
        "logs/somecommand_{sample}.log"
    shell:
        "scripts/run_somecommand.sh {input} {output} {log} {sample}"
```

Note: If you are working on a Mac and don't have `realpath` you can install with `brew install coreutils` it's a super handy command.